# complex mysql inner join query with null values

Tags: mysql

my query is as follow:

```
SELECT cp.p_id AS p_id
  ,cp.p_id AS pk
  ,cp.name_first AS name_first
  ,cp.name_last AS name_last
  [...]
FROM tbl_E AS cp
INNER JOIN tbl_B, tbl_C, tbl_A, tbl_D AS cpr
WHERE cp.p_id = tbl_C.p_id
  AND tbl_C.sp_id = tbl_A.vsp_id
  AND tbl_B.p_id = cp.p_id
  AND cpr.pr_id = tbl_A.pr_id
  AND (
    cp.p_id = 339066
    OR cp.p_id = 103688
    OR cp.p_id = 321496
    )
GROUP BY cp.p_id
ORDER BY name_last ASC LIMIT 0,1000;
```

I expect to get 3 rows but I get less than 3 rows because tbl_C.p_id does not contains all the cp.p_id. How to change the query to get exactly 3 rows?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's cause you are doing a `INNER JOIN` ... change it to a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` like below

```
SELECT cp.p_id AS p_id
  ,cp.p_id AS pk
  ,cp.name_first AS name_first
  ,cp.name_last AS name_last
  [...]
FROM tbl_E AS cp
LEFT JOIN tbl_B ON tbl_B.p_id = cp.p_id
LEFT JOIN tbl_C ON cp.p_id = tbl_C.p_id
LEFT JOIN tbl_A ON tbl_C.sp_id = tbl_A.vsp_id
LEFT JOIN tbl_D AS cpr ON cpr.pr_id = tbl_A.pr_id
WHERE 
    cp.p_id IN (339066,103688,321496)
GROUP BY cp.p_id
ORDER BY cp.name_last 
LIMIT 0,1000;
```